# how to implement Draggable element in ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi Guys My requirement is to make an element draggable across the screen and set the position of the element to the place where users stops dragging. So far I am able to make a element draggable across the screen but once released it is going back to its old position (position where it was earlier) I am using ngDraggable directive of angular. Sorry I am new to Ionic and angular. Any help will be highly appreciated.
My code goes as follows

```
<div ng-drag="true" id="draggableAxis" ng-style="{{draggedStyle}}" ng-drag-success="onDragComplete($data,$event)">
            <img src="img/axis.png" >
            <img ng-src="img/other.png" style="width:75px"> 
        </div>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.draggedStyle = {top: '96px',
    right: '90px'};
    var onDraggableEvent = function(evt, data) {           
      if(evt.name=='draggable:start'){
        console.log('draggable-start');
        console.log(data.x);
        console.log(data.y);
      }else{
        console.log('draggable-end');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.element.centerX +'  '+data.element.centerY);
        console.log(evt);
        $scope.setPosition(data);
        
    } 
}
    $scope.onDragComplete=function(data,evt){
       console.log("drag success, data:", data);
       console.log(evt);
    }// this fn doesnot gets triggered
    $scope.$on('draggable:start', onDraggableEvent);    
    $scope.$on('draggable:end', onDraggableEvent);
     
    $scope.setPosition=function(data){
        $scope.draggedStyle = {
            top: data.x+'px',
            right:  data.y+'px'
        };
     }
```

[SCREEN SHOT OF MOBILE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9TPv.png)

Comment: Not familiar with that library but I'm not seeing anywhere where you are defining the drop area. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-draggable indicates how to define the drop area

Comment: With that, most drag-and-drop solutions I've seen have both source and destination areas defined.

Comment: i donot want to drop element in a particular area i want the element to stay where user leaves dragging. Do I need to define drop area for that

Comment: I have taken reference from the same site. There we have drag and drop implemented

Comment: I have been struggling with this since two days

Comment: Do you have a plunker setup and I can look at it?

Comment: @IosSteveos I am onto it

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/nepJYsVvV8c3dCyMh8wA?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the fix to https://plnkr.co/edit/fVaIUVvAd7jLETkwVepm?p=preview

One of the problems was

```
ng-style="{{draggedStyle}}"
```

which should be

```
ng-style="draggedStyle"
```

Also, I switched the setPosition method to flip the x and y and used left because x indicates position from the left and not right.

```
$scope.setPosition = function(data) {
    $scope.draggedStyle = {
      top: data.y + 'px',
      left: data.x + 'px'
    };
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my day. Now position are changing correctly.

Comment: Please don't forget to indicate the answer was correct

Comment: Done..One question How to prevent the element from sliding when released.

Comment: It's sliding because data.y and data.x are where you mouse pointer is.  It's then putting the top most left part of the image to where the mouse pointer is.  You might take the difference of the element top and left from the y and x on drag start and then subtract it from data.x and data.y when setting position.

Comment: Updated the plunker. Thanks a lot for your help.